# Backbone RESTful CRUD 404

Tags: rest, backbone.js, crud

So I am trying to implement CRUD into my Backbone app by using the [book from Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#restfulapps). One of the problems that I encounter is, that although I am currently using the same code for the NodeJS server with express/mongoose/path I get 404 for all CRUD operations. Here is my currently folder structure on localhost

```
/
/myApplication/ (working dir)
/myApplication/js (contains all js files from Backbone app)
/myApplication/mongoServer.js (the server app)
```

So according to the guide the only thing that has to be set is the url in the collection

```
myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model: myModel,
 url: '/api/myModels'
 ...
})
```

What I would expect is, that once I add a model, as it is part of the collection, it creates a collection (if it did not exist) and then syncs it with the server. This probably happens, BUT with one exception

```
POST http://localhost/api/todos 404 (Not Found)
```

Of course I see that thats not correct as it probably needs to look at the path

```
POST http://localhost/myApplication/api/todos
```

because the mongoServer.js is in the folder of myApplication. I do not really know how to solve this problem. Maybe one could change routes or maybe there is a flaw in my logic about my implementation?

Edit: Also to clarify, i've already tested

```
url: '/myApplication/api/myModels'
```

the XHR finishes loading, but the POST is still 404.

Comment: Did you try the url to see if it's working at all ?

Comment: *edit* using http://localhost:3000/myApplication/ works perfectly, so i guess it can only work if the port is given or the express runs on port 80, right?

Comment: You can use ngnix to re-route the api to go through port 80. It's either that, or you can use the fully qualified URL (with the port), but that would be considered as a cross domain XHR request, which is another issue.

Comment: Or you could use express to serve the js resources in which case you wouldn't need a fully qualified URL, I wouldn't think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general problem i was having was the setup with the Express app server. The line that caused the trouble was

```
app.configure(function() {
 app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "public")));
});
```

Which basically tells express that the static path to the app is in the public folder (which i did not have apparently). As the express server listens to the port you choose via

```
app.listen(3000);
```

the page that you actually want to visit (like your index.html or static.html) can be found under

```
http://localhost:3000/index.html or static.html
```

without any */myApplication* following the localhost. This also helps with the general url settings in the app itself as it really just needs to be */api/myModels*